# Elasticsearch: Using Collections class method in groovy script

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I am trying to use Collections class in groovy for some processing to create an entity centric index. I get the below error:

Caused by: `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Collections for class`

However, my code runs in grrovy compiler the way I want it to.

Below is the code that I am using:

```
def Indices_sqn = []
int n = 0
while (n != list_Eventname.size()) {

    int index = Collections.indexOfSubList(list_Eventname, sequence_srch);
    if (index != -1) {
        int end_index = index + sequence_srch.size()
        Indices_sqn.add(index)
        n += end_index
    }

    println Indices_sqn
}
```

Comment: Maybe security problem? See this link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/modules-scripting-security.html#_script_classloader_whitelist

Comment: I am also looking into that. Meanwhile I am using a solution which doesn't use Collections. Thanks